# does url redirection happens during connection or after connection

Tags: url, redirect, urlconnection

As soon as the dns look up is performed then connection establishement happens between client and server.

My doubt is whether url redirection happens while connection establishment or after establishment of the connection?
I am using http server.And please provide detail answer.When the url direction happens?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to share this article with you which could give you a pretty good idea on how the whole navigation work.

http://igoro.com/archive/what-really-happens-when-you-navigate-to-a-url/

Comment: I have read this article.but in java's httpurlconnection class setInstanceFollowRedirects method is present.I am getting confusion here.While establishing the connection is redirection performed?

Comment: or after establishing the connection,step 3 is sending http request is done according to that article.so after sending this http request server may respond with a url redirection.so actually at what stage url redirection takes place.please help me.thank u..

Comment: I haven't tried the API but based on the API description I guess when the server return redirection response back to the client, if the FollowRedirects set to be true then it will follow the redirected url, otherwise it will not. I am just guessing!!

Comment: While connection establishment only redirection takes place or while sending the http request url redirection takes place??please clarify my doubt..thank you

Comment: first in the underlying a TCP connection is established. All HTTP request/response will then work on top of it. So URL redirection is no difference.